# I'm trying to add a diffuse color in the paint slot in texture paint mode for blender 3.1. Can't seem to find it

Tags: texture-painting

I'm trying to add a diffuse color in the paint slot in texture paint mode for blender 3.1. Can't seem to find it. All I can find in the texture slot are base color, specular , roughness, metallic, normal, bump and displacement. Can't find diffuse.

Comment: Hello, if you are talking about the Principled BSDF, the Base Color input is the same as Diffuse

Comment: Okay. Thank you